# Eigenvalues of a Matrix with Positive Entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm attempting a homework problem and have an idea for proving the result that relies on whether or not matrices with positive entries have only real eigenvalues. Is this true?

For $2\times 2$ matrices this is easy to show. However I'm not sure how to decide if it is true for general $n \times n$ matrices.

I know that the Perron-Frobenius Theorem says the spectral radius of a positive matrix is itself an eigenvalue. If the result I'm asking about is true, can I use this to prove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in this answer
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99845/properties-of-eigenvalues-of-general-nonnegative-matrices

the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&1 \\ 1&0&0&1 \\ 0&1&0&1 \\ 0&0&1&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has some complex eigenvalues. This remains true, if we add $0.01$ to every entry, making the matrix positive with some complex eigenvalues. (Of course, calculations have to be done by some software...)

Comment: +1 for genuinely add that link!

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.